# compile latex source into unicode string

Tags: unicode

I have a bunch of one-line LaTeX strings which I would like to compile into unicode strings (preferably using Python, but any solution will do). Specifically achieve

```
in: '\"o{A}c'
out: 'öAc'
```

(I realize there is [latexcodec](https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/latexcodec), but it I found it unreliable so I'm looking for an alternative approach.)

I figure the only reliable way to do so is to fall back to a system LaTeX compiler, specifically

- to compile the string into a PDF, and
- to read the output from the PDF file.

Is there a more streamlined approach to this? For example: Is is possible to compile LaTeX into a unicode string in memory rather than a PDF?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you mean by “compiling into unicode strings”? What's the input and the expected output?

Comment: `biber` can do this for you.

Comment: Questions about Python are off topic here. However, stripping off braces shouldn't be difficult, while decoding from LICR to Unicode can be done by looking at the `<enc>enc.dfu` files, for instance `t1enc.dfu`.

Comment: I don't really care so much about Python, if there is any solution I'll see how I can adapt it to my use case.

Comment: Reading the output from the PDF file wouldn't necessarily help.  At least in my experience, when copying directly from a PDF viewer, the result usually has to be corrected by hand.

Comment: @Johannes_B Care to give more details?

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biber/blob/cfe6cfb34dd92be94141714f9a7d8dea7da21afe/lib/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm

Comment: i can give you a small latex example, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) does a decent job for not too complicated documents. Try

```
echo "\\\"o{A}c" | pandoc -f latex -t plain
```

or, in Python,

```
def latex_to_unicode(latex_string):
    '''Convert a LaTeX string to unicode.
    '''
    # Use pandoc for the job
    try:
        # This works in Python 3.4+
        return subprocess.check_output(
            ['pandoc', '-f', 'latex', '-t', 'plain'],
            input=latex_string
            )
    except TypeError:  # unexpected keyword 'input'
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            ['pandoc', '-f', 'latex', '-t', 'plain'],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
            )
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate(latex_string)
        return stdout.replace('\n', ' ').strip().decode('utf-8')
```